# Cannot pull newly-added top-level directory into sparsely-checked out SVN repository

Tags: svn

Our SVN repository is quite large, and pulling the whole thing takes some time. When checking out at home, I was pleased to discover the sparse checkout feature; I checked out the whole repository to a depth of 1, then pulled each top-level directory (directly under the trunk) that I needed to a depth of infinity. Until now this has been brilliant.

Recently I added a new directory under trunk. When I do a `svn up`, I get nothing. The TLD I added will not sync.

I normally use Tortoise SVN, so I tried doing this from command line. I tried explicitly specifying the name of the directory, adding `--depth infinity`, adding `--force`. None of these tricks has worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried on a fresh wc?  We've had similar issues where I work, presumably due to some unspecified damage to the contents of the .svn subdir; a fresh checkout worked.  Also, I assume you've done an "svn ls" on the base URL to make sure it's showing up properly, and an "svn info" on your wc to make sure it's pointing at the correct URL?

Comment: (Also may be worth giving a quick gander at the .svn/entries and the .svn/all-wcprops files.  While I can't pretend to know their format well, sometimes we've seen the problem just by looking in those.)

Comment: I gave you +1 for this, because I have been wanting to do exactly what you did, not having the same problem, but you answered my question with your question!...

Comment: Yeah I was pretty excited when I found out about sparse checkouts. Our repository is several GB large, and I only need a handful of TLDs.

Comment: Another thing I've learned subsequently... if you do a svn up with a --depth argument, you need to use --set-depth to change the depth setting. This has caused me similar problems to the one described in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had another directory that was incorrectly retrieved (checked out into the same tree). The update was halting when it got to that directory. When I deleted it and repeated a `svn up`, I got the newly-added directory, as expected.